# HTML getnext using lxml parser

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I am trying to parse a page with html code as below:

```
<html>
..
<h2><span id='identifiedid'>Identified Header<span>...</span></span></h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href='links i want'></a>...</li>
  <li><a href='links i want'></a>...</li>
  <li><a href='links i want'></a>...</li>
</ul>
..
</html>
```

I am using a Python code for parsing the page with an lxml parser. I am able to identify the id of the element indicated using xpath. But, the links I need to access don't have a class/id to identify them and they also are not under the span of the id. Is there any way to access these links of the adjacent element? I have tried getnext(), but it is not able to access the ul and li elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent of the `span` using `getparent()` and then get the `ul` element using `getnext()`:

```
root = etree.XML(open("lx.xml").read())
span = root.xpath("//span[@id='identifiedid']")[0]
print span.getparent().getnext().xpath('li/a/@href')
```

Comment: the document has `ul` elements earlier as well. I would need to identify the `ul` element immediately after the specific `id`

Comment: `getparent().getnext()` returns the `ul` element that is located immediately after `h2`.